# Controller method/browser not recognizing @RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editComment/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showOfficeComment(@RequestParam(value="id", required = false) Long id) {
        Office office;          
        office = officeServiceImpl.find(id);
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("editComment", "command", office);
        return result;
    }
```

When I put the address in the browser with an id at the end (...editComment/100), I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
```

I have the following method that works perfectly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/officeForm/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView showOfficeForm(@RequestParam(value="id", required = false) Long id) {
        Office office;
        if (id == null) {office = new Office();}
        else {office = officeServiceImpl.find(id);}
        office.setDepartments(new ArrayList<Department>());
        List<Department> departments = departmentServiceImpl.findAll();

        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("officeForm", "command", office);
        result.addObject("departments", departments);
        return result;
    }
```

Can anybody explain what's happening here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam` as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: Then I get "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
"

Comment: Does `officeServiceImpl.find(100)` return anything?

Comment: Yea.  I got it working, might have been due to my DB being empty but I'm not convinced.  All I did was add an HttpServletRequest param and bound an attribute to it.  Seems unrelated to my problem.